# gettin request/query parameters with less code

Tags: laravel

Is this:

```
$paginate = $request->get('paginate');
```

Equivalent to this, for getting a query param if it is present or assign to the associated variable "null" it it is not present:

```
       if ($request->has('paginate')) {
            $paginate = $request->get('paginate');
        } else {
            $paginate=null;
        }
```

Comment: ``$paginate = $request->get('paginate');`` should work. It will be null if ``paginate`` query parameter is not set.

Comment: You can also assign a null coalescing operator `$paginate = $request->get('paginate') ?? null;`

Comment: Or, use the `->input()` method: `$paginate = $request->input('paginate', null);` -  `$paginate` will be whatever `?paginate=` in the Query String, or `null` if it is not present.

Answer (score -1):

According to `get()` method documentation:

*This method belongs to Symfony HttpFoundation and is not usually needed when using Laravel.*

Alternatively you can use `filled` and `$request->paginate`

So it checks if the request has the "item"and it has value.

```
$paginate = null;
if ($request->filled('paginate')){
    $paginate = $request->paginate;
}
```

Comment: why complicate things when you can simply do ``$paginate = $request->get('paginate');``?

Comment: Because at some point you will need to check if the $paginate is null or not

Comment: even if at some point if you wish to check if ``$paginate`` is null, you can simply do ``if($paginate === NULL) { ... }`` If the ``paginate`` param is not set/empty, the ``$paginate`` will be ``NULL`` by default.

Comment: yep, thats what we do here as well. If the paginate has value(conditions inside if) do something, else $paginate is null and do something else

Comment: the solution is to reduce the code and not to increase unnecessarily !!